# Как сделать "резиновые" столбцы в таблице?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, table

**Описание**

Есть `HTML` таблица с четырьмя столбцами.
Cтолбцы в таблице разделяют ширину между собой поровну.
То есть каждый из четырех столбцов забирает себе по `25%` из `100%` ширины таблицы.
Столбцы 2 и 3 я сделал фиксированными, назначив им ширину `50рх`.
Остались столбцы 1 и 4, которые делят между собой оставшееся пространство.

> HTML

```
<table class="table border-bottom" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Менеджер таблиц</b>
            </td>
            <td class="table-cell-small">
                <i class="fas fa-fire push"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="table-cell-small">
                <i class="fas fa-bell push "></i>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="head-menu-accaunt"><!--блок любой ширины-->

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> CSS

```
.table-cell-small {/*  ширина ячейки таблицы 50px  */
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
}
```

**Требование**

Мне нужно, чтобы столбец 4 брал минимум пространства, а все остальное забирал столбец 1. Тут у меня появляются два вопроса:

1. Как этого добиться?
2. Можно ли сделать то, что я хочу на чистом `CSS`?

Comment: Покажите код, как пытались это сделать. Минимум пространства для 4го столбца - это сколько?

Comment: скиньте свой код суда

Comment: @Избытоксусликов Добавил код

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Добавил код

Comment: тут всего 2 столбца

Comment: @Избытоксусликов Присмотритесь

Answer (score 4):

Это легко достигается на **Grid Layout**.

Колонка по минимальному размеру делается `auto`, всё оставшееся пространство берут `fr` столбцы в соответствии с пропорцией, в данном случае такой столбец один.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 50px 50px auto;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
  height: 70px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">берёт остаток</div>
  <div class="item">fix</div>
  <div class="item">fix</div>
  <div class="item">по минимальному</div>
</div>
```

Почитать по Grid Layout можно тут - https://metanit.com/web/html5/13.1.php

Answer (score 1):

Как например:

```css
.table-cell-small {/*  ширина ячейки таблицы 50px  */
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.table-cell-first {
  width: 100px;
}

.table-cell-last {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

```html
<table class="table border-bottom" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="table-cell-first">
                <b>Менеджер таблиц</b>
            </td>
            <td class="table-cell-small">
                <i class="fas fa-fire push">icon-1</i>
            </td>
            <td class="table-cell-small">
                <i class="fas fa-bell push ">icon-2</i>
            </td>
            <td class="table-cell-last">
                <div class="head-menu-accaunt"><!--блок любой ширины-->
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, odit, amet. Dolor labore iure voluptate laudantium blanditiis officiis doloribus minus.
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Задать таблице `table-layout: fixed;`, чтобы ячейки в `50px` были как раз `50px`, а не меньше или больше.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так.

```css
.table-cell-small {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
}
table td {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #dedede;
}

.table-auto {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table border-bottom" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Менеджер таблиц</b>
            </td>
            <td class="table-cell-small">
                s
            </td>
            <td class="table-cell-small">
               s
            </td>
            <td class="table-auto">
                <div class="head-menu-accaunt">
                  b
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Придайте каждому столбцу свой класс, и укажите расстояние в процентах.

```
.table {
width: 100%;}

.stolb4 {
width: 5%;}
```

тем самым всё остальное пространство заберут себе другие столбцы. Если нужно что бы сама таблица была не на всю страницу заключите её в div обозначив границы поля для div

Comment: Дело в том что `.stolb4` может местить в себе элемент который может выходить за его пределы. Например элемент может быть больше 5%. Яуже так думал сделать.

Comment: @Ezdrael какие это элементы? Картинки? Если это картинки то вы можете задать класс ячейке в которой будете размещать картинку и так же задать условия что бы картинка не выходила за рамки

Comment: Это цельнострочный текст